# Как передать в функцию указатель на одномерный массив, чтобы вернуть в параметрах его [массива] изменения

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Существует код:

```c
…
//Функция, которая запрашивает указатель на одномерный массив
void AbstractName(int* row_size){
  int rows;scanf_s("%d",rows);
  row_size = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*rows);
  for (int i = 0; i < *rows; i++)
   scanf_s("%d",&row_size[i]);
}
…
///Где-нибудь в основной части:
//Объявление указателя на одномерный массив и его инициализация "нулём"
int* row_size = (int*)malloc(0);
AbstractName(row_size);
…
```

Так вот: после выполнения функции "AbstractName" в основной части программы row_size по-прежднему хранит адрес того участка памяти, который был использован для его инициализации (т.е. "0").

Вопрос: как передавать в функцию указатель массива, чтобы с ним после выполнения кода функции можно было работать?

Comment: `void AbstractName(int** row_size){ ... *row_size = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*rows); ...}` и вызов `...AbstractName(&row_size);...`

Comment: Спасибо, я постараюсь разобраться в вопросе благодаря вашему ответу.

Comment: @SergeyNaN *for (int i = 0; i < *rows; i++)* - Зачем  тут звёздочка перед rows?!

Comment: @avp, можно же просто по указателю, зачем огород городить из двойного?

Comment: Вы бы ещё поняли, что значит `malloc(0)`...

Comment: @0andriy, для того, чтобы переместить в вызывающую программу выделенный по malloc адрес, для чего же еще? Впрочем, идея у вас правильная, я бы предпочел для такой задачи другой прототип -- `int *AbstractName();`, явно возвращающий адрес. Просто показал, как можно сделать передавая, его в аргументах

Comment: @avp, часто вызов `malloc()` без сопутствующего `free()` в рамках одной функции — это *layering violation*. Я бы делал так `void xxx(int *array, size_t size);` ну или `int ...` если надо ошибки возвращать.

Comment: @0andriy, мне всегда претил подобный формализм, сколько людей столько и мнений о том, как делать красивый код. И кстати, вы в своем предложении собираетесь делать malloc в вызывающем коде?

Comment: @0andriy: Совершено не верно. Главное назначение `malloc` заключается именно в том, что бы **не** писать сопутствующее `free` в этой же функции. Динамическая память предназначена в первую очередь для того, чтобы создавать объекты, время жизни которых не ограничено рамками блоков, в т.ч. телами функций. Скорее наоборот, если пара `malloc`/`free` располагается в одной функции - это в 4 случаях из 5 ошибочное использование динамической памяти там, где динамическая память совсем не нужна.

Comment: @AnT, Мне необходимо уточнить, поскольку программа маленькая, то `malloc()` и `free()` должны вызываться на одном уровне (даже, если они вынесены в отдельные функции), для меня это был уровень `main()`. В случае сложных программ конечно вы правы.

Comment: Большое спасибо за все комментарии, однако уже первого мне действительно хватило для решения проблемы. Тем не менее, уточнить пару моментов стоит, так как заданный мною вопрос каким-то образом породил дискуссию...
Во-первых, это лишь часть программы, именно поэтому я забыл сменить "*rows" на какую-либо другую переменную.
Во-вторых, про присваивание NULL вместо malloc(0) я также узнал совершенно недавно.
Спасибо ещё раз за все комментарии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, если вы исходному указателю уже присвоили адрес динамически выделенной памяти, то в функции вам следует использовать функцию `realloc` вместо `malloc`. Иначе у вас произойдет утечка памяти.

Чтобы изменить в функции исходный указатель, его следует передавать по ссылке, то есть через указатель на указатель.

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f( int **p, size_t n )
{
    int *tmp = realloc( *p, n * sizeof( *tmp ) );

    if ( !tmp )
    {
        free( *p );
    }
    else
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) tmp[i] = ( int )i;
    }


    *p = tmp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 5;
    int *a = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) a[i] = ( int )i;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    n *= 2;

    f( &a, n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

В общем случае по выходе из функции следует проверять, не равен ли указатель NULL, чтобы избежать неопределенного поведения.

Если вы не хотите освобождать память под уже выделенный массив в случае ошибки перераспределения памяти внутри функции, то вы можете возвращать логическое значение из функции, говорящее об успехе или провале выделения памяти.

Например,

```
_Bool f( int **p, size_t n )
{
    int *tmp = realloc( *p, n * sizeof( *tmp ) );
    _Bool success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) tmp[i] = ( int )i;
        *p = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

И нет никакой необходимости инициализировать указатель следующим образом:

```
int* row_size = (int*)malloc(0);
```

Достаточно написать изначально

```
int* row_size = NULL;
```